# Backupme - Connection Manager missing

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm using this shell script below.  I have it in app/console/command/BackupShell.php

When I run the script I get this error:
Fatal error: Class 'ConnectionManager' not found in app/Console/Command/BackupShell.php

What am I doing wrong?

```
class BackupShell extends Shell {
var $tasks = array('ProgressBar');

public function main() {
    //database configuration, default is "default"
    if(!isset($this->args[0])){
        $this->args[0] = 'default';
    }

    //rows per query (less rows = less ram usage but more running time), default is 0 which means all rows
    if(!isset($this->args[1])){
        $this->args[1] = 0;
    }

    //directory to save your backup, it will be created automatically if not found., default is webroot/db-backups/yyyy-mm-dd
    if(!isset($this->args[2])){
        $this->args[2] = 'db-backups/'.date('Y-m-d',time());
    }

    App::import('Core', 'ConnectionManager');
    $db = ConnectionManager::getDataSource($this->args[0]);
    $backupdir = $this->args[2];
    $seleced_tables = '*';
    //$tables = array('orders', 'users', 'profiles');

    if ($seleced_tables == '*') {
        $sources = $db->query("show full tables where Table_Type = 'BASE TABLE'", false);
        foreach($sources as $table){
            $table = array_shift($table);
            $tables[] = array_shift($table);
        }
    } else {
        $tables = is_array($tables) ? $tables : explode(',', $tables);
    }

    $filename = 'db-backup-' . date('Y-m-d-H-i-s',time()) .'_' . (md5(implode(',', $tables))) . '.sql';

    $return = '';
    $limit = $this->args[1];
    $start = 0;

    if(!is_dir($backupdir)) {
        $this->out(' ', 1);
        $this->out('Will create "'.$backupdir.'" directory!', 2);
        if(mkdir($backupdir,0755,true)){
            $this->out('Directory created!', 2);
        }else{
            $this->out('Failed to create destination directory! Can not proceed with the backup!', 2);
            die;
        }
    }

    if ($this->__isDbConnected($this->args[0])) {

        $this->out('---------------------------------------------------------------');
        $this->out(' Starting Backup..');
        $this->out('---------------------------------------------------------------');

        foreach ($tables as $table) {
            $this->out(" ",2);
            $this->out($table);

            $handle = fopen($backupdir.'/'.$filename, 'a+');
            $return= 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `' . $table . '`;';

                $row2 = $db->query('SHOW CREATE TABLE ' . $table.';');
                //$this->out($row2);
                $return.= "\n\n" . $row2[0][0]['Create Table'] . ";\n\n";
                fwrite($handle, $return);

            for(;;){
                if($limit == 0){
                    $limitation = '';
                }else{
                    $limitation = ' Limit '.$start.', '.$limit;
                }

                $result = $db->query('SELECT * FROM ' . $table.$limitation.';', false);
                $num_fields = count($result);
                $this->ProgressBar->start($num_fields);

                if($num_fields == 0){
                    $start = 0;
                    break;
                }

                foreach ($result as $row) {
                    $this->ProgressBar->next();
                    $return2 = 'INSERT INTO ' . $table . ' VALUES(';
                    $j = 0;
                    foreach ($row[$table] as $key => $inner) {
                        $j++;
                        if(isset($inner)){
                            if ($inner == NULL){
                                $return2 .= 'NULL';
                            }else{
                                $inner = addslashes($inner);
                                $inner = ereg_replace("\n", "\\n", $inner);
                                $return2.= '"' . $inner . '"';
                            }
                        }else {
                            $return2.= '""';
                        }

                        if ($j < (count($row[$table]))) {
                            $return2.= ',';
                        }
                    }
                    $return2.= ");\n";
                    fwrite($handle, $return2);

                }
                $start+=$limit;
                if($limit == 0){
                    break;
                }
            }

            $return.="\n\n\n";
            fclose($handle);
        }

        $this->out(" ",2);
        $this->out('---------------------------------------------------------------');
        $this->out(' Yay! Backup Completed!');
        $this->out('---------------------------------------------------------------');

    }else{
        $this->out(' ', 2);
        $this->out('Error! Can\'t connect to "'.$this->args[0].'" database!', 2);
    }
}

function __isDbConnected($db = NULL) {
    $datasource = ConnectionManager::getDataSource($db);
    return $datasource->isConnected();
}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

Is this 2.x code?

```
App::import('Core', 'ConnectionManager');
```

is deprecated/wrong in 2.x and should be

```
App::uses('ConnectionManager', 'Model');
```

and also be placed at the top of the file, right after the `<?php` tag